SQL Server cannot pinpoint the correct row
I have this query
create table A 
(
    [CODEID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PRJID] [int] not null,
    [CODEVALUE] [varchar](200) NULL
)

create table B 
(
    [CODEID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CODENAME] [varchar](100)
)
go

insert into A 
select 1,99,'ABC'
union
select 2,99,'5-0-0'
go

insert into B
select 1, 'ONE'
union
select 2, 'TWO'

;with dt as 
(
    select cast(replace(CODEVALUE,'-','') as int) VAL 
    from A
    join B on B.CODEID = A.CODEID and B.CODENAME = 'TWO' and A.PRJID = 99
)
select MSG 
from 
    (select 
         case when VAL>25 then 'BRAVO' end MSG 
     from dt) q
where 
    MSG is not null

I expected to return MSG, instead the server tries converting the 'ABC' into an int, hence the error.
But if I remove
where MSG is not null

it works

Well yes, cast(replace(CODEVALUE,'-','') as int) is attempting to convert 'ABC' to an int... what do you really want to do?

The join pinpoints to a single row, don't know why it should interrogate the entire table.... more, what does the difference having the where clause?

Perhaps you should be using TRY_CAST/TRY_CONVERT? But the real problem appears to be you are storing values you want to treat as numerical in a string based data type.

"The join pinpoints to a single row, don't know why it should interrogate the entire table" You assume SQL Server would perform the JOIN first; that is a mistake. SQL Server will perform operations in the order it feels most appropriate; you don't tell it the how to do something, you tell it what you want.

Why shoul I use TRY_CAST when it works without the where clause? What makes the difference?

Because SQL doesn't work the way you think it does. You are describing the results you desire, how the engine goes about obtaining them is up to it. And for some reason when you add a where clause it determines that the best way to obtain the data access it all before joining it. You always have to write "safe" queries when you have messed up data like this. Thats why try_cast/try_convert exist.

@RaduB. explain the logic, not what you think the solution should look like. This query is very, very unusual. Storing numbers in text fields is a bug any way you look at it. As for tries converting the 'ABC' into an int that's your own code, not the server's

To find out more inspect the execution plan with and without the where clause and see what its doing.

I would guess that because you have MSG is not null this forces the column defined as MSG to be derived the start with; as then SQL Server has less rows from dbo.A to JOIN to dbo.B, and there's no indexes to help SQL Server seek to the data at the JOIN point. So That means that the expression case when VAL>25 then 'BRAVO' end must be derived, which means that cast(replace(CODEVALUE,'-','') as int) must be derived and, oh... 'ABC' isn't a valid int.

This looks like an XY Problem: There's a problem X and you assume the solution is Y. When Y doesn't work, you ask about Y, not the real problem. Right now we have to guess what the real problem is. We even have to guess what the expected results are. They are not I expect all rows, the expected results are the actual values you expect, in table form.

@Dale K Obviously, I don't want to convert 'ABC' into a number, therefor I specify the values for the search in the join clause

If you explain the actual problem and the actual expected output we can create a SQL query that produces it. Right now we have to guess the results and have to decipher a failing query to determine the logic. Things may be obvious to you, but the query is failing and SQL experts are asking what is this doing?

Panagiotis Kanavos
I am expecting the server to find the row with the values specified in the join clause and return the correct value, meaning '5-0-0', which can be converted into an int.
When it does this w/o the last where clause it works, but with the where clause it doesn't.
To me, it appears an inconsistency in the server's plan

You are still thinking that SQL Server will parse the query in a "top down" fashion, @RaduB. . There is nothing is that query to force SQL Server to derive the JOIN first. It takes the query as a whole and works out the best order of operations to get the results you asked for.

@Thom A
Why is working without the where clause?

TRY_CAST does help. It returns NULL if the cast fails instead of throwing an error. That doesn't mean the query and the table design aren't bad. They still are

Bceause when the WHERE is missing the order or operations changes, @RaduB. . Different queries, different methods.

Ok, thank you for the TRY_CAST, I'll definitively use it.

If you compare the execution plans of the two queries you'll see that the actual operation is just two table scans and a JOIN, despite the query's complexity. (That also means you could replace all this with a single, simple JOIN). The server has to filter A when you use WHERE msg is not null before it can join the tables.

@Panagiotis Kanavos
As anybody could see, in that field are only strings, and the logic of the app knows that some of them could be converted to numbers. For me the answer should reveal how to elude that error. Finally, I find a solution.

@RaduB. the "anybodies" are saying for an entire day that SQL doesn't work the way you assumed. ThomA's answer is telling you the same thing. When I told you to check the execution plans I expected you to do so, in which case you'd have seen that the cast is performed in different places in each case

@RaduB. the logic of the app is unknown to both SQL Server and everyone that answered until know. If you explain that logic we can tell you how to convert it to efficient SQL. Creating extra tables is no solution

The problem here is your understanding of how SQL Server (and many other data engines) work; you are under the impression that it will derive the JOIN in your CTE dt first, and therefore when it goes to derive the expression VAL an error cannot occur as only one row would have that expression run again. This understand is wrong.
When running a query it is the data engine that determines the most efficient way to determine the results you are after; you tell the data engine what you want and the data engine works out how it will get those results.
Here you also seem to be under the impression that your 2 queries, 1 with WHERE MSG IS NOT NULL and the other without, would be run identically; this is again wrong. SQL Server will analyse each query and determine the best method for getting the results for that query; 2 queries can results in 2 methods.
Most likely, here, the inclusion of WHERE MSG IS NOT NULL means that SQL Server has determined that the best action is the first derive that expression, as it'll filter the number of rows from the table dbo.A down, and then it'll have less rows to JOIN to the table dbo.B. To derive that expression, it first needs to work out if MSG has the value NULL, which means it needs to derive the expression CASE WHEN VAL > 25 THEN 'BRAVO' END. This, however, also needs to derive a further expression to be calculated: CAST(REPLACE(CODEVALUE, '-', '') AS int). Now we have columns from the tables, so it can run the expression against the dataset in dbo.A:
CAST(REPLACE('5-0-0', '-', '') AS int)
CAST(REPLACE('ABC, '-', '') AS int)

Which becomes:
CAST('500' AS int)
CAST('ABC' AS int)

And ahh, we have a problem; what "int" value is 'ABC'? It's not a valid value and so you get an error.
When you omit the clause WHERE MSG IS NOT NULL, however, SQL Server likely determined that JOINing the data first is "best", as it doesn't have any WHERE clauses now and there no indexes anywhere to help it work out what rows to seek to, so a scan of both tables and JOINing them seems the most fit. Then after the JOIN it can derive the SELECT.
So what is the solution? Honestly, don't store data you need to treat as numerical in a string based column; if a value needs to be treated as a numerical value use a numerical data type (int, decimal for example). If you "must" store such data in a string based column, use a TRY_ function to result in the conversion returning NULL is the value isn't valid:
TRY_CAST(REPLACE(CODEVALUE, '-', '') AS int)
TRY_CONVERT(int,REPLACE(CODEVALUE, '-', '')


We can actually evidence this using the query plans. If we inspect the (estimated) plan for the query with WHERE MSG IS NOT NULL and look at the table scan of dbo.A we can see the filter is applied at the scan:
[
If we look at the query without the WHERE, however, we can see the filter is on PRJID = 99.

Therefore in the second query, when the CONVERT is derived, only the row with the value '5-0-0 is derived.

How can I enforce the second plan to be used? The original query is much more complicated and neither TRY_CAST doesn't function. We cannot design 2 fields separately for numeric and string, because we don't know apriori what kind of data comes, but definitely we know at the interrogation time if the string is numeric or not...

You don't force it. It appears you have overly simplified the problem; as Panagiotis Kanavos suggested, it looks like you have an XY Problem, @RaduB. . I suggest you post a new question asking about X, rather than Y (as you have here). Though, again, I suspect the real problem is your design.

As a workaround I declare a table variable holding the MSG field from
select case when VAL>25 then 'BRAVO' end MSG from dt
and then I could select the value from the table with the where clause
where MSG is not null
without error
