UNION SELECT from different databases
I have a table with a lot of records made for many years, which will never be changed, so I decided to move old records to the table in the separate database. Then I made a view like
create view qry_big_table as
SELECT id, name FROM db1.dbo.big_table
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name FROM db2.dbo.big_table

In [some_other_view] I am using something like
SELECT t.*
FROM [other_table] as t
INNER JOIN (
  select convert(int, b.name) as id from [big_table] 
  WHERE ... -- b.name is always integer with this condition
) as b on b.id=t.id

That [other_table].id is integer and [big_table].name is varchar and may contain any data, but for this view I added WHERE conditions and it always returns integers - JOIN works, no error messages.
But after splitting that [big_table] between two databases I replaced [big_table] with [qry_big_table] in [some_other_view] and it started to produce error messages like

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12000.00' to data type int

With "WHERE ..." conditions I am using, [qry_big_table] still returns only integer values and no '12000.00' in the "name" column.
Well, I fixed it like this:
SELECT t.*
FROM [other_table] as t
INNER JOIN (
  select b.name as id from [big_table] 
  WHERE ... -- b.name is always integer with this condition
) as b on b.id=convert(varchar(9), t.id)

But why does "UNION" affects this what else could happen?

Read through the comments and answer on this question and you will understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78611483/sql-server-cannot-pinpoint-the-correct-row

Is there a reason you can't ALTER TABLE to ensure all the columns' corresponding datatypes are identical?

TRY_CONVERT instead of CONVERT would allow you to only convert proper values and avoid the error. It's still bad though, because you might be joining pears and apples. Another downside of all this is that you might not be able to use indexes, but judging from the data/question, that might not be a problem anyway

Dale K, so, when SQL Server works with one table, it first takes all records where varchar column has integer values, like my "WHERE" condition requires, and only after that converts varchar into integer. And with UNION view SQL Server first tries to convert varchar to int from ALL 21732614 records in both tables and only after it will obey WHERE conditions?

In your case that appears to be the case. But the real takeaway from the linked answer is that how the query engine obtains your data is not directly related to how you write your query. It will use what it considers to be the most efficient method which could be the complete reverse of the order you wrote your query. Hence when dealing with messy data like this you shoukd always write defensive queries using try_convert for example
